# Gmail clipping html email, updated sizes

Tags: html, gmail, html-email

Today I have found that standard <102kb rule for html emails size in Gmail is not working any more...

Gmail clips off emails, even <102kb size!

Answer (score 0):

After some manual tests I found out that the issue is not in Gmail. ActiveCampaign lets me to send letters with size up to 102kb without clipping off in Gmail.

Same time MailChimp made my code weight bigger, so letters starting from ~65kb are clipped. Tested this using several letters with different weight via MailChimp and ActiveCampaign.

My way to fix this is to make my emails smaller. To make your email smaller try:
 - https://htmlcompressor.com/compressor/
 - delete indentation, double spacing
 - delete unused styles

MailChimp support did not give me proper answer for this issue, so more info from community will be helpful

Comment: How did you test in MailChimp? Any way you can show us how you arrived at 65kb? That's a pretty specific number.

Answer (score 0):

As Dmytro has mentioned in his reply to the original issue, [minimizing your code](https://fulcrumtech.net/resources/preventing-gmail-from-clipping-your-emails/) such as removing unnecessary nested HTML elements, line breaks, code comments and whitespace can help while keeping your email as short as possible.

And I cannot reiterate this enough but its best to test your email design as much as you can before committing to sending your campaign to your subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Gmail actually. If you're using any email marketing tool, It depends on the limit set by the tool. We are using an in-house email marketing application that allows up to 95kb. When we were using Easysendy, it was a little higher than 95kb.

I had an HTML of 109kb which was obviously clipped by Gmail. I tried 102, 98, 96, 95 in our in-house tool. For all other sizes except 95, it got clipped in Gmail.

So, You'll have to experiment/check with the email marketing tool that you're using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. –